# Cannot load message class for [robot_position/mymsg]. Are your messages built?

Tags: ros, rostopic, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I correctly followed the steps as mentioned here: [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv)
Home>assign2>src>robot_position
Where **robot_position** is my package name. I created a directory named **msg** inside it and inside msg directory, I made mymsg.msg file. I wrote this inside it:

```
float64 x
float64 y
```

then I added these lines in package.xml file:

```
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

then I added message dependencies in **CMakeLists.txt** file as:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
```

then I wrote message_runtime in **CMakeLists.txt** file  as in here:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES robot_position
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime geometry_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

then I added this:

```
  add_message_files(
       FILES
       mymsg.msg
     )
```

and then this:

```
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   geometry_msgs   std_msgs
 )
```

and then did this: `catkin_make install`

Did  I miss anything?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230025/cannot-load-message-class-for-%5Brobot_position/mymsg%5D.-are-your-messages-built?/) by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-03-24**:
Is there a mymsg.h file inside catkin_ws/devel/include/your_package_name/? If the msg is compiled properly, there should be a .h file generated in the mentioned folder.

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-03-24**:
Also, after compilation, you can check the msg details by

`rosmsg list | grep mymsg`

and

`rosmsg show your_package_name/mymsg`

**Comment by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on 2016-03-24**:
Thanks for replying,
Is there a mymsg.h file? Yes.
After compilation, yes I can check msg details by `rosmsg list | grep mymsg`

but `rosmsg show your_package_name/mymsg` gives error:
Unable to load msg [your_package_name/mymsg]: Cannot locate message [mymsg]: unknown package [your_package_name]..

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-03-24**:
what is the output of `rosmsg list | grep mymsg`? By the way, when I say 'your_package_name', I mean to use your package name (which is robot_position)

**Comment by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on 2016-03-24**:
Sorry, I'm just a beginner.

```
rosmsg list | grep mymsg
```

gives this:

robot_position/mymsg

**Comment by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on 2016-03-24**:
and `rosmsg robot_position/mymsg` gives this

```
rosmsg is a command-line tool for displaying information about ROS Message types......
```

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-03-24**:
It s ok. We were all beginners once :). The actual command is `rosmsg show robot_position/mymsg`.  You can do`rosmsg -h` to see more options of rosmsg

**Comment by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on 2016-03-24**:
It works fine, shows what's intended

float64 x
float64 y

but I'm having problem when I echo any rostopic! and following message appears

```
Cannot load message class for [robot_position/mymsg]. Are your messages built?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before echoing a rostopic, I ran this:    `source ~/assign2/devel/setup.bash`

and then I did `rostopic echo (topic-name)`
and it worked.

Note that: assign2 is the name of the directory where I have all my files!

---

Originally posted by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) with karma: 37 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-03-26**:
You can add `source ~/your_folder/devel/setup.bash` into `.bashrc` permanently so that it will be sourced automatically each time you open new terminal :)

**Comment by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on 2016-03-28**:
Thank you! Can you explain how to do that? I couldn't find .bashrc file!

**Comment by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on 2016-03-28**:
Thank you!
I entered this in terminal: `gedit ~/.bashrc` and it opened `.bashrc` file in which I put this `source ~/my_folder/devel/setup.bash` and saved it.
It indeed is helpful and time-saving!